# Iterate over DataMembers in WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework-4.1

We have an existing database and a script that would take an email, find the pieces of data we wanted (i.e., Name, Address, Email, etc.) and then insert the data into the database as field/value pairs (columns of "FieldLabel" & "FieldValue").

I am now implementing an API (WCF Service) to replace this email parsing using C# with Entity Framework.  I am creating a DataContract, "Details", which contains DataMemebers of "Name", "Address", "Email", etc that gets passed to the API.  I then have an InsertData() method which I want to use to take each data member and use its name as the FieldLabel and it value as the FieldValue.

For instance, with Name = "Brian" and ZipCode = "11111" I want to create the label/value pairs of Name/Brian & ZipCode/11111.

Here is what I am after in pseudo-code:

```
DetailsTable _detail = new DetailsTable();       // EF table object

foreach (datamemeber in Details)
{
   _detail.FieldLabel = datamemeber.toString();
   _detail.FieldValue = datamember.Value();
}
```

**UPDATE:  added the code for my Details DataContract**

```
[DataContract]
public class Details
{

    public LeadDetail()
    {
        FirstName = "";
        LastName = "";
        StreetAddress = "";
        City = "";
        State = "";
        ZipCode = "";
    }

    public LeadDetail(string firstName, string lastName, string streetAddress, 
        string city, string state, string zipCode)
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
        StreetAddress = streetAddress;
        City = city;
        State = state;
        ZipCode = zipCode;
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string FirstName;
    [DataMember]
    public string LastName;
    [DataMember]
    public string StreetAddress;
    [DataMember]
    public string City;
    [DataMember]
    public string State;
    [DataMember]
    public string ZipCode;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems that need to be addressed to make your pseudocode work. First you need to iterate over the fields of an instantiated Details object to retrieve the key/value pairs, and next create a entity from DetailsEntity to perform the insertion. If I understand your problem correctly differentiating the name of the Details(username, zip, ...) and DetailsKeyValue(FieldLabel, FieldValue) classes will improve the understandibility of your code.

Here is the code that will iterate over the fields of a Details object and insert an equivalent EF entity, DetailsKeyValue.

```
using (var context = new DetailsKeyValueContext()) {
    foreach (FieldInfo field in details.GetType().GetFields()) {
        var detailsKeyValue = new DetailsKeyValue();
        detailsKeyValue.FieldLabel = field.Name;
        detailsKeyValue.FieldValue = field.GetValue(details) as string;
        context.DetailsKeyValue.Add(detailsKeyValue);
    }
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

And here are the code first entity and context classes.

```
public class Details
{
    public string Name;
    public string Zip;
    public string Email;
}

public class DetailsKeyValue
{
    public string FieldLabel { get; set; }
    public string FieldValue { get; set; }
}

public class DetailsKeyValueContext: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<DetailsKeyValue> DetailsKeyValue { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<DetailsKeyValue>()
            .HasKey(x => x.FieldLabel);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your 'pseudo-code' looks almost identical to the real code to achieve this.  All you need is a DbContext wrapped around it, a connection string that has the same name as your context (e.g. DetailsContext) and you are ready to go.

**Edited:**

```
Details details = Populate();  // Populated from parameter passed in

using (var context = new DetailsContext())
{
   DetailsEntity _detail = new DetailsEntity();       // EF table object

   foreach (datamemeber in details)
   {
      _detail.FieldLabel = datamemeber.Type;
      _detail.FieldValue = datamember.Value;
   }

   context.SaveChanges();
}
```

[this is a good reference](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx) to start with.

Comment: When I implement this code it complains about "Details is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'".  I have added the DataContract for Details to my original post.

Comment: Sorry, the `foreach` should be `foreach(datamember in details)` so that the details you are iterating over is the actual instance of the collection, not the the type of the collection.